# Add padding to hex string for remaining bytes

Tags: php, hex

I never ever worked with Hex-strings in PHP (or whatever language). Now I'm wondering how I could add padding to a hex string with 00 (in hex) up until it reaches 8 bytes.

```
$hex = bin2hex("MAIN");
```

How can I add `00` for the remaining bytes so that `$hex` holds 8 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-pad.php) :

```
$hex = str_pad(bin2hex("MAIN"), 16, '00', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Output : `"000000004d41494e"`

Is that what you want ?

Comment: So 8 bytes is always 16 characters? (1 byte is in hex represented with 2 characters?)

Comment: Yes, 1 hexadecimal character = 4 bits ; 2 hexadecimal characters = 8 bits = 1 byte.