# How to add up hex string and perform NOT-operation on it?

Tags: php, hex

I've got a long string consisting of HEX-characters:

```
$hex = '004d41494e0000000048001B030C1A050EEFF500'.
       'F5FB0000400804FBF101F1F201F2F301F3FA00FA' .
       '48454c4c4fFA00FAFB0008400804FBF101F1F201F2F30' .
       '2F3574f524c44EF';
```

From this string I have to calculate a 'verify' by adding up the bytes within this string. And afterwards perform a NOT-operation on it.

In the documentation (this is a string to control a serial device) the verify should be `1C5B` and after the NOT it should be `E3A4`

As I'm completely [new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318520/add-padding-to-hex-string-for-remaining-bytes) to HEX I've got no clue how to tackle this 'problem'. I found a way to perform a NOT operation [in php: ~](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) . But how to sum up the data in hex and end up with `1C5B`.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $hex_array = str_split($hex, 2);
 foreach ($hex_array as $byte) {
   $sum += hexdec($byte);
 } 

 echo "Sum: ", $sum, "\n";
 echo dechex($sum);
```

**EDIT**

Explanation:
Assuming the input string has even number of characters we can start from the first byte and take two hex characters (representing one byte). That's what [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) does. Then we loop over each of that two-character substrings and parse them to number using [dechex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) that we then add to the main sum. After that the only thing left is to represent that sum as hex number, using [hexdec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php).

References from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php):

- [array str_split ( string $string [, int $split_length = 1 ] )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)
- [string dechex ( int $number )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)
- [number hexdec ( string $hex_string )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: I like the cleaniness of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$hex = '004d41494e0000000048001B030C1A050EEFF500'.
       'F5FB0000400804FBF101F1F201F2F301F3FA00FA' .
       '48454c4c4fFA00FAFB0008400804FBF101F1F201F2F30' .
       '2F3574f524c44EF';

$n = strlen($hex);
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i+= 2)
{
    //fetch 2 chars from string
    $byte = $hex[$i].$hex[$i + 1];
    $byte = intval($byte, 16);
    $sum += $byte;
}

//0x1C5B;
print sprintf('0x%4X', $sum)."\n";
$sum = ~$sum;
//To avoid the problem: prints FFFFE3A4, and not E3A4
$sum = $sum & 0xFFFF;
//E3A4
print sprintf('0x%4X', $sum)."\n";
```